# Detect (meaningless) assignment to temporary object

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, temporary-objects, compiler-options

Is there any compiler option that allows you to get a warning when you try to assign to temporary object?

Example:

```
struct S {
    S op() { return S(); }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.op() = s; // assign to temporary. Wants to warn here.
}
```

I know that you can declare the return type of `op` as `const` to prevent such a situation, but now I'm interested in is the compiler options only.

You can use any popular modern compiler.

Comment: How do you know (in general) that this is meaningless? The assignment may have side effects: `Database db; db.SinkValue() = 5;`

Comment: @KerrekSB Suppose I just want to get a warning. Is assigning meaningless - will not be considered.

Comment: `S& operator=(const S&) & = default;` is a better option than returning a const instance

Comment: @juanchopanza any modern: gcc, clang, vc++

Comment: So put that in your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza see last sentence in question.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki is declaring `operator=` as default for lvalue object implicitly deletes `operator=` for rvalue object?

Comment: @alexolut it doesn't *delete* the rvalue version. the compiler will simply not generate any other assignment operator

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I thought that `not generate any other assignment operator` includes deleting it for rvalue object too. Am I right?

Comment: @alexolut a deleted function is considered as an existing one

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50438 is the bug report for getting this in clang.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100721 is the bug report for getting this in gcc.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler may not be able to tell useful side effects.

Compilers do warn for

```
int test( S & data );

test( S.op());
```

Comment: That's not valid C++, even if a certain compiler who shall not be named allows it.